# Modify Territory Assignment Rules using Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, territory-management

Is it possible to use the Metadata API to modify existing Territory Assignment rule criteria? Currently we are using the Salesforce Mapping tool to build territories and then import into ETM. The criteria selection for creating the assignment rules is limiting to one criteria. Therefore, we need to modify the Territory Assignment rule that is created. I didn't see the Territory Assignment rules as metadata that is not configurable. I was wondering if this approach is possible? I was looking for an example that shows the basic approach to accomplish this type of metadata update. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible through Metadata API. This is still an issue according to this post: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqRXAA0

Comment: why can't you use the MDAPI on `Territory2Rule` [Metadata Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_territory2rule.htm) - assuming you are using Territory 2.0

Comment: That looks like it should work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easily done via VS Code, or IDE of your choice (ETM 2.0), just add to package.xml:

```
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Territory2Model</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Territory2</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Territory2Rule</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Territory2Type</name>
    </types>
```

Make sure ETM is active in the destination org first. Then don't forget to run the rules in the destination org. Under Territory Models, click View Hierarchy, then the "Run Assignment Rules" button (and the "Run Opportunity Button", if you have the custom Apex installed that creates that as well).

I'm still working on the additional XML to copy the Opportunity Apex code (created separately as per other posts) and "Users Assigned to Territory" and their Roles under each Territory (since that can take a lot time to configure as well), but I think it's just an assignment rule and/or user profiles that need to copied also for the latter. will update post here once I figured it out.